# OperationalError("MySQL Connection not available.")

Tags: python, mysql, telegram-bot

I have set up a telegram bot to fetch data from my mysql db.
Its running well until like after 1 day..And It just cannot connect:

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mysql/connector/connection.py", line 809, in cursor
raise errors.OperationalError("MySQL Connection not available.")

I have checked that the script is perfect and I can even run it perfectly on the server, while at the same time if it run through the bot , it throws the above errors.

Even so ,it will resume to normal after I reboot the apache server. Can anyone help??? Thanks first.

Comment: Is the mySQL server running?

Comment: mysql server is running. I can use the same script to fetch data manually on server while it throws the above error to the telegram bot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that its not related to my bot. But sql connection called by my django server (not orm, but mysql.connector.)
I didn't close the connection properly (I closed cursor). After I closed the connection `conn.close()`immediately after the fetch, the problem vanished.

Yet I still dun understand why it doesn't cause any problem when i run the script manually. I feel its something about connection time. I am no expert of mysql, in fact I am just a amateur of programming. see anyone can give further solution. (I have changed the title in order to make my problem more relevant.)